# How to set QSizePolicy in QSS stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

Is it possible to change the `QSizePolicy` property from the stylesheet?

So far I know every `QWidget` has the property `sizePolicy`. But the `QSizePolicy` constructor takes two arguments; so I'm not sure how to set this property from a QSS file. Also calling:

```
MyWidget
{
    qproperty-sizePolicy: 2; // "Expanding", Expanding, 0 0 also does not work
}
```

Does not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is not possible out of the box. I will have to subclass whatever `QWidget` I want and add two `Q_PROPERTIES` for each direction of the `QSizePolicy`. See this [thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/34036/qss-qproperty-sizepolicy/3).